# Unable to deminify Webpack CSS output

Tags: css, webpack, minify

For some reason, Webpack and associated plugins and modules refuse to output my Sass/CSS in non-minified way. I've scavanged the web for a possible solution or a simple config parameter but I can't really find anything on the matter. I deem it strange because it appears to me to be a pretty straightforward setup.

**main.scss** (input)

```css
.example {
   display: grid;
   transition: all .5s;
   user-select: none;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

**styles.css** (output)

```css
.example{display:grid;transition:all .5s;user-select:none;background:linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black)}
```

**Webpack config** (simplified)

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    optimization: {
        minimize: false,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'styles.css',
        }),
    ],
};
```

**postcss.config**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
  ],
};
```

Comment: So out of curiosity I ask why you don't want to minimize the css conversion result from scss to css?

Comment: To be able to make the CSS of the build readable to humans. It know it comes off as improper but it's required at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the end. I had simply tried the same thing without "sassOptions" earlier.

Reconfigure your Webpack configuration as such:

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        sassOptions: {
            outputStyle: 'expanded',
        },
   },
},
```